# Numbers in numbered list do not appear in the right places in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

IE7 does not show numbers of a numbered list in correct positions. I configured the numbers with `relative` position. In IE8 and IE9 the numbers are shown properly.

This is the CSS:

```
#thumbs li p{
    text-align:center;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    right: -7px;
    float:left;
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
    <div id="thumb_caixa">
        <p>Clica per veure més imatges</p>
        <ul id="thumbs">
            <li class='active' rel='1'><p>1</p></li>
            <li class='active' rel='2'><p>2</p></li>
            <li class='active' rel='3'><p>3</p></li>
            <li class='active' rel='4'><p>4</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The URL of the site with the problem is: http://abs.marcmorales.es/index.php?i=1&s=5&p=11

Where is the problem?

Comment: If i remember correctly IE7 is awful with relative positioning (and also awful in general)

Comment: @AlanFoster Would you suggest just using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) and a custom stylesheet, then?

Comment: The problem is technically IE7, but the core problem is the approach with the CSS. Don't hack together conditional comments when you can just write better, cross-browser CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the use of positioning to get the p tag centered?

I suppose this will be okay, too:

```
#thumbs li p {
    text-align:center;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I would change about this:

- Get rid of the `p` tag. It's superfluous.
- Change the `#thumbs li` to have no `background-image`, but instead a `background-color`.
- Add in a padding to `#thumbs li` so the numbers are centered.
- Add a `color`.

Comment: Different browsers handle paddings and margins in lists differently. If you change one padding, you'll need to explicitly set all paddings and margins on both the li and the lu in order to keep it cross-browser compatible.